# Spring how to get Maven artifact name in runtime

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration requirement , where I need to externalize the libraries and properties file from my war file. I am able to achieve this through Maven assembly plugin, where i create a zip file which may contain

```
lib/*.jar 
properties/{artifactId}/*.properties
```

The reason I am adding the artifact Id to the path is, I will be creating 100s of wars in future and would need to distinguish between them.

This wars will not contain Web.xml and the Initializer is part of one of my libraries file.
THe Initializer should know the artifactId in order to load the correct properties.

With maven, the maven artifact details gets published to

```
META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml
```

If I could move these files to

```
META-INF/maven/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/pom.xml
```

My application would be able to read the artifact id from pom.properties.

I need help in achieve this.

Or if there are any other approach please help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven archiver component does that: [see here at addMavenDescriptor element](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html). It doesn't seem to be possible to customize the paths of these files.

But I guess every property you need can just be placed in a specific file and so you just have to create a resource file (properties like) containing all the information you want and let Maven filter that file for you.